# Hide public page from logged in users?

Tags: private

Got a private site, with 4 public pages. The public pages include: Login, lost password, register and preview. The preview page shows content set to anyone only.
I need the preview page to be hidden from logged in users only. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a page template to check if user is loggedin. And if it does then redirect user to website homepage (configurable), otherwise show page content.

This is the simple condition you can use to check if user is loggedin.

```
<?php
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {

        wp_redirect( home_url( '/' ) );
        exit;

    } else {

        the_content();

    }
?>
```

Comment: That's great. I am glad I could help. If it helped you solve your problem, don't forget to accept the answer. :)